# Problem with jQuery easing / animate

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-animate, easing

this works:

```
function prodLanding(){
$("#productsLanding").animate({opacity: 'toggle', width: 'toggle'}, function(){
$("#productsAll").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 800);
});
}

$("#prodLandSelect .prod1").click(function(){
$('#product1').load('products/chicken-jerky/index.html', function() {
prodLanding();
});
return false;
});
```

But this does not:

```
    function prodLanding(){
    $("#productsLanding").animate({ left: 200 }, {duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutElastic'}, function(){ $("#productsAll").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 800);});
    }

    $("#prodLandSelect .prod1").click(function(){
    $('#product1').load('products/chicken-jerky/index.html', function() {
    prodLanding();
    });
    return false;
    });
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have jquery ui core effects.

Comment: I figured it out: I had to set the div to relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're passing the parameters incorrectly.

Try:

```
$("#productsLanding").animate({ left: 200 }, 'slow', 'easeOutElastic'}, function(){         
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

.animate( properties, [duration,] [easing,] [complete] )
properties: A map of CSS properties that the animation will move toward.
**duration: A string or number determining how long the animation will run.**
**easing: A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.**
complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.